# Is $I^\times = I,$ that is is the adjoint of the identity operator the identity operator?

Tags: functional-analysis

Fundamentally this would make sense, but I have not found anything that explicitly states if this is true or not.

Comment: You might find this useful https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3662827/if-i-is-identity-operator-on-hilbert-space-h-then-show-that-i-i

Comment: Have you tried explicitly checking this yourself? What is your definition of an adjoint?